# jest test async function which neither return promise nor accept callback

Tags: jestjs

```js
//index.js
export let usersList = [];

export function getUser() {
  fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users")
    .then((x) => x.json())
    .then((users) => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        usersList = users;
      }, 2000); //fake delay
    });
}

getUser();
```

```js
//index.test.js
const { getUser, usersList } = require("./index");

it("should fetch users and assign to usersList", () => {
  getUser();
  expect(usersList.length).toBe(10); //Error: Expected: 10, Received: 0
});
```

Comment: Why _doesn't_ it return a promise? That would make it more testable and more useful (and the caller's still welcome to ignore it if they don't need it).

Comment: Is there no other way without returning the promise? even if it does return a promise how do you write a test for that? my requirement is to test the `getUser` by validating the `usersList`, BTW the above example is extracted from Angular & NGXS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question!

###### TL;DR

Create and use below utility function ([found here](https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/2157#issuecomment-1272503136))

```js
const waitForPromisesAndFakeTimers = async () => {
    do {
        jest.runAllTimers();
        await new Promise(jest.requireActual('timers').setImmediate);
    } while (jest.getTimerCount() > 0);
};
```

full example:

```js
//index.test.js
const { getUser, usersList } = require("./index");

it("should fetch users and assign to usersList", (done) => {
    jest.useFakeTimers();
    getUser();
    waitForPromisesAndFakeTimers().then(() => {
        expect(usersList.length).toBe(10); //passed
        done();
    })
});
```

There are other options too but not as optimal as the above one IMO, read about other options and issues with them in this [github issue](https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/2157)